# Closing all windows in WPF after one has been closed

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way I could close all windows after the user closes one of them, and here is the important part: without using `App.Current.Shutdown()`, but rather by invoking `close` on remaining windows individually?

My idea was to just invoke `close` on each of the remaining windows in the `Window_Closing` event handler method. There's one problem, though. Suppose I have two window classes, `A` and `B`. I create one instance of `A` and `B` - `a` and `b` respectively. If I close window `A`, then it invokes the `Window_closing` event handler method and calls `b.close()` there. Then in the `B` class (`A` and `B` are window classes, they both inherit from `Window`) `Window_closing` method is invoked (because I've just called `B.close()`), and `B::Window_closing` calls `a.close()` and it results in exception cause I've already closed `a`.

What is the right way to solve this?

Comment: does exit the whole application?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `App.Current.Shutdown()`? If there's a requirement you've not described, there may also be an alternate solution you're not thinking of.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in having a "main window" and "tool windows", so that closing the main window closes all of them and closing tool windows does, well, only just that - then in the `App.xaml` there's a friendly option just for that!

That's [Application.ShutdownMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx)

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
    ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose"
    >
</Application>
```

Note that here, the "MainWindow" in question, is **the main window** the application starts with (or the one you set as main, if you played with that during the app's lifetime).

EDIT: afterthought: That will of course close all the windows, but I'm not actually sure if it calls normal "Close", or just shutsdown the whole application. Sorry, you'd need to check it for yourself. If you're interested in my opinion, that's the way you should/could do that easily, and if you really-really-need to shutdown the app by "Close()"ing every window, then I sense you're doing something wrong here, as if I remember correctly, "Window.Close()" may be cancelled.

EDIT2: yup, `Window.Close()` can be cancelled. Please [see this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.close.aspx):

> Closing a window causes the `Closing` event to be raised. If the `Closing`
>   event isn't canceled, the following occurs: (...)

So looping over the window collection and calling 'Close' doesn't really guarantee that the windows will really be closed and the app may still be left running afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Handle `Window.Closed`event instead of `Window.Closing` which would be closing all the opened windows other than `MainWindow`. I am not calling `Close` method for `MainWindow` because this is the main thread which will cause application terminating.

```
private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var windows = Application.Current.Windows;
    foreach (var item in windows)
    {
       if ((item as Window).Title.ToLower() == "mainwindow") continue;
       (item as Window).Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I copied it to both class A and class B `Window_closing` method, and the program doesn't exit.

Comment: Please remove the if condition from the snippet which will close the application, Also please move your code to Window.Closed event instead of WIndow.Closing

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
private static bool WindowsClosing;
public static void CloseAllWindows()
{
   if(WindowsClosing) return;
   WindowsClosing = true;
   var windows = Application.Current.Windows;
   foreach (var wnd in windows.OfType<Window>())
   {
     wnd.Close();
   }
}
```

And call that method from your `Window_Closing` (or rather `Window_Closed` if you don't need to cancel) events